# Problems with xmonad settings compilation

Tags: haskell, gentoo, xmonad

I am having problems compiling the settings file for my xmonad installation.

When I try to compile the settings file with:

```
ghc -o xmonad xmonad.hs
```

I get the following [errors](http://hpaste.org/53581).

I've posted some additional information if it would be of any help:

system:
    Linux 2.6.36-gentoo-r5 #1 SMP Mon Feb 14 11:54:45 GMT 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P8400 @ 2.26GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

ghc --version:
    The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.3

ghc-pkg list (the entries in asterisks are 'hidden', the rest are 'exposed'):

```
Cabal-1.8.0.6
X11-1.4.6.1
array-0.3.0.1
base-3.0.3.2
base-4.2.0.2
bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
bytestring-0.9.1.7
containers-0.3.0.0
directory-1.0.1.1
***dph-base-0.4.0***
***dph-par-0.4.0***
***dph-prim-interface-0.4.0***
***dph-prim-par-0.4.0***
***dph-prim-seq-0.4.0***
***dph-seq-0.4.0***
extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.1
ffi-1.0
filepath-1.1.0.4
***ghc-6.12.3***
***ghc-binary-0.5.0.2***
ghc-prim-0.2.0.0
haskell98-1.0.1.1
hpc-0.5.0.5
integer-gmp-0.2.0.1
mtl-1.1.0.2
old-locale-1.0.0.2
old-time-1.0.0.5
pretty-1.0.1.1
process-1.0.1.3
random-1.0.0.2
rts-1.0
syb-0.1.0.2
template-haskell-2.4.0.1
time-1.1.4
unix-2.4.0.2
utf8-string-0.3.6
xmonad-0.9
xmonad-contrib-0.9
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any particular reason you are trying to do this by hand rather than just either `xmonad --recompile` or hitting `mod-q` whilst running xmonad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ghc --make xmonad.hs
```

Comment: Thanks very much :] !!!
It worked.. I'll check whether the actual changes do work and will reply if there's still something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When building xmonad, it's preferable to execute

```
xmonad --recompile
```

rather than manually executing GHC. The reason for this is that the keybinding to rebuild and restart xmonad internally calls the same function that `xmonad --recompile` does, so `xmonad --recompile` will succeed if and only if the keybinding would successfully restart xmonad with the new settings. (For comparison, `ghc --make xmonad` will sometimes succeed when `xmonad --recompile` would fail.)